# Taxonomy term parent widget alternative

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a huge hierarchical vocabulary of terms and adding a new child to a specific term can be hard using the default multi-value select list widget.

Can I use an autocomplete widget or -better- an entity browser instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself using [Select2 contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/select2) + very little customization in my module:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'taxonomy_term_myvocabulary_form') {
    // Show parent select as select2 (if enabled)
    if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('select2')) {
      $form['relations']['parent']['#type'] = 'select2';
    }
  }

  return $form;
}
```

This is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would integrate with that widget automatically, but I really like [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen). Doesn't work on mobile though.